# Rubocop claims for too many 'if' statements

Tags: ruby, rubocop

I am measuring my code for a Rails app using Rubocop. This is my code:

```
def ratings_treatment
    if @rating.advertise_id
      advertise = Advertise.find(advertise_id)
      rating_average(advertise)
    elsif @rating.product_id
      product = Product.find(product_id)
      rating_average(product)
    elsif @rating.combo_id
      combo = Combo.find(combo_id)
      rating_average(combo)
    else
      establishment = Establishment.find(@rating.establishment_id)
      rating_average(establishment)
    end   
end
```

It does not pass a test regarding `if`. It is claimed that there are too many `if` statements.

I thought of splitting the code into some checker methods, but was wondering if there is some better way to get good metrics and still write good code.

Comment: What does RuboCop actually say? I'm pretty sure it's not "Too many if statements".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could use a switch statement to assign the argument for `rating_average`:

```
def ratings_treatment
  average = case
            when @rating.advertise_id then Advertise.find(advertise_id)
            when @rating.product_id   then Product.find(product_id)
            when @rating.combo_id     then Combo.find(combo_id)
            else Establishment.find(@rating.establishment_id)
            end
  rating_average average
end
```

Although Rubocop will complain with

> Style/EmptyCaseCondition: Do not use empty case condition, instead use
>   an if expression

You could also simplify your if expression:

```
def ratings_treatment
  average = if @rating.advertise_id
              Advertise.find advertise_id
            elsif @rating.product_id
              Product.find product_id
            elsif @rating.combo_id
              Combo.find combo_id
            else
              Establishment.find @rating.establishment_id
            end
  rating_average average
end
```

Answer (score 3):

If your `@rating` has associations set up then you could say:

```
def ratings_treatment
  obj = @rating.advertise || @rating.product || @rating.combo || @rating.establishment
  rating_average(obj)
end
```

or even:

```
def ratings_treatment
  rating_average(@rating.advertise || @rating.product || @rating.combo || @rating.establishment)
end
```

or perhaps something fancy (and overkill for only four branches):

```
def ratings_treatment
  rating_average(
    %w[advertise product combo establishment].lazy.map { |m| @rating.send(m) }.find(&:present?)
  )
end
```

or maybe even:

```
def rated_object
  to_result = ->(m) { @rating.send(m) }
  %w[advertise product combo establishment]
    .lazy
    .map(&to_result)
    .find(&:present?)
end

def ratings_treatment
  rating_average(rated_object)
end
```

I'd go so far as to suggest that something like the above `rated_object` method really should be a method on `@rating`. You should be able to ask a rating for the thing that was rated without having to manually spin through all the possibilities.

You could even patch that `lazy.map...` stuff into `Enumerable` if you wanted something in `Enumerable` that behaved like `e.m1 || e.m2 || e.m3 || ...` (been there, done that) all the way down to short circuiting.

I have no idea what Rubocop would make of any of these shenanigans though.

Comment: `%w[...].find { |m| @rating.send(m).presence }`

Comment: @sawa But doesn't that `find` call give you the first `m` where `@rating.send(m)` is truthy rather than the first truthy *result* of `@rating.send(m)`? i.e. you'd get one of the strings `'advertise'`, `'product'`, ... rather than the result of calling the named method.

Comment: @sawa And the `#presence` call isn't necessary since the association methods shouldn't be returning empty strings or `false` or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic case of a style violation that has a deeper underlying cause, i.e. a modelling problem. In  your case, it looks like what you're actually trying to achieve is a [polymorphic association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations). If you change your `Rating` to:

```
# app/models/rating.rb
class Rating < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :rateable, polymorphic: true
end
```

you can have the `Rating` relate to any number of things, by simply adding this to the other end of the association:

```
# app/models/product.rb
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :pictures, as: :rateable
end
```

Your original method, if it is even needed anymore, becomes:

```
def ratings_treatment
  rating_average(@rating.rateable) 
end
```